# Torus action/limit approach to show that open embedding $U_\tau \subseteq U_\sigma$ implies $\tau$ is face of $\sigma$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, toric-varieties

### Context

Both the Fulton and Cox/Little/Schenck books on Toric Varieties include an exercise to show that if an inclusion $\tau\subset \sigma$ of cones induces an open embedding $U_\tau \hookrightarrow U_\sigma$, then $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703972/if-a-subcone-tau-subset-sigma-induces-an-open-embedding-u-tau-hookrig) tries to answer this exercise using only the earlier material in Fulton, but I am interested in a solution that uses the torus action, what Fulton alludes to with his hint "If this is difficult now, try it after you have read about orbits in Chapter 3".

### Problem

Cox's book has a more guided exercise, stated as follows:

> **3.2.10.** In Proposition 1.3.16, we saw that if $\tau$ is a face of the strongly convex rational polyhedral cone $\sigma$ in $N_\mathbb{R}$, then $U_\tau=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C [S_\tau])$ is an affine open subset of $U_\sigma = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C [S_\sigma])$. In this exercise, you will prove the converse, i.e., that if $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ and the induces map of affine toric varieties $\phi: U_\tau \to U_\sigma$ is an open immersion, then $\tau \preceq \sigma$, i.e., $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$.

> (a) Let $u,u' \in N\cap \sigma$, and assume $u+u'\in \tau$. Show that
> $$\lim_{t\to 0} \lambda^u(t) \cdot \lim_{t\to 0}\lambda^{u'}(t) \in U_\tau.$$

> (b) Show that $\lim_{t\to 0}\lambda^u(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\lambda^{u'}(t)$ are each in $U_\tau$. Hint: Use the description of points as semigroup homomorphisms.

> (c) Deduce that $u,u'\in \tau$, so $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$.

### Thoughts

It is clear to me that (b) implies (c), and that (c) is sufficient. I am stuck showing/interpreting (a), and seeing how to get (b).

But, for (a), what does this multiplication mean, for points not in the torus? For $t\in \mathbb C^*$, we have $\lambda^u(t), \lambda^{u'}(t) \in T$ the torus, so we have multiplication. But in the limit, we no longer land in the torus (unless $u,u'=0$). Should I interpret these points as semigroup homomorphisms $S_\sigma \to \mathbb C$, and then the multiplication is the product of the semigroup homomorphisms? Even so, I'm having trouble with knowing when some limits converge.